# GraphQL playground - sending Cookie as Http Header "disappears"

Tags: cookies, graphql, apollo, graphql-playground, restdatasource

I'm testing some implementations in the GraphQL Playground, in which I want to send a specific cookie, so that I can fetch it in my resolver. I'm using the built in Http Headers pane in the playground:

[image]

However, when I add headers named either `Cookie` or `cookie`, it doesn't show up when I try to console.log it in my resolver. All other custom Http Headers show up with no issues.

[image]

As seen in the above screenshoot the testheader appears, but the cookie header doesn't. I'm using [cookieParser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-parser), which might to blame for the `cookie` header disappearing, however I'm not sure. Here is a screenshot of my console.log section:

[image]

And when I try to console.log the `req.cookies`, I get nothing, which is to be one of the benefits of using the cookieParser.

[image]
[image]

My ApolloServer implementation is as follows:

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs: schema
  resolvers,
  dataSources: () => ({
    // ...
  }),
  context: ({req, res}) => ({
    models,
    session: req.session,
    req,
    res
  }),
  // ... and the rest is not important
});
```

Creating a "custom" cookie header could do the trick, such as `somecookie: <key>=<value>`, but I don't think that's the best practice, and would prefer to avoid that. I'm hoping someone out there got an idea why my cookie `header` doesn't appear, or what I can do for it to appear?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

After extensive searching, documentation reading and etc. I figured out how I could make this work.

In the GraphQL playground settings (gear icon), located in the upper right corner of the window:

[image: Gear icon in graphql playground]

I changed the line `"request.credentials"` to `"include"` and SAVING the settings in the UI. Read more [here](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-playground#settings).
This line is taken directly from the documentation:

```
'request.credentials': 'omit', // possible values: 'omit', 'include', 'same-origin'
```

Then following that, I opened the developer tools window (usually F12), went to the tab `Application`. In here I simply added a cookie as seen in the screenshot. That cookie was sent together with my request.

[image: Developer tools application tab]

Comment: I did the same, however, still not working ...

Comment: What about in the GraphQL Playground desktop app?